# JS/AJAX failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net

Here I am trying to make user choice home page while user clicks the lnkfavourite button on any page of the website. When I set up other page as home page it works as expected but not with default.aspx. This page is at root dir.
 VB page behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 lnkFavorite.Attributes("onclick") = "clearFave();"
end sub
```

JS/AJAX:

```
 function clearFave() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "u=default.aspx";
    req.open("POST", "/myaccount/favorite.aspx", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    //req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    req.send(params);     //Error here

    var img = document.getElementById("ctl00_pageContent_imgFavorite");
    if (img) {
        img.src = img.src.replace("/favorite.png", "/unfavorite.png");
    }
    alert("This page is now set as your BERT home.");
  }
}
```

Favorite page behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    Try
        Dim u As String = "default.aspx"
        If Request("u") IsNot Nothing Then
            u = Request("u").Replace("|", "&")
        End If
        Profile.SetPropertyValue("favorite", u)
        Profile.Save()
    Catch ex As Exception

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change post URL, make the URL specific. Like this `http://doman:port/a-page`

```
req.open('POST', 'http://yourdomain:port//myaccount/favorite.aspx')
```

Comment: @Zoe, same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I removed '/' from post url and it worked 
From:

```
 req.open("POST", "/myaccount/favorite.aspx", true);
```

To:

```
 req.open("POST", "myaccount/favorite.aspx", true);
```

:)